# How to use escape chars when reading a file?

Tags: java, android, escaping

I have a method that reads a random joke from a file in raw, and then displays it, but i can't figure out, how to set a new line.
All the jokes in the line are 1 line, but obviously they are more than one so i use `\n`. For instance the line says `"Hi! \n Hi to you too"` When i use my code instead of:

```
Hi!
Hi to you too
```

it gives me

```
Hi! \n Hi to you too
```

I tried to append it, and that didn't work with the code bellow also tried to enter the joke in array and then display it from that array, did't work either... Any ideas would be much appreciated...

```
InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader
         (getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.vicove));
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
         int numLines = 1;
         Random r = new Random();
         int desiredLine = r.nextInt(numLines);

         String theLine="";
         int lineCtr = 0;
        try {
    while ((theLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
    if (lineCtr == desiredLine) {
    break;
    }
        lineCtr++;
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            }

     textGenerateNumber.setText(String.valueOf(theLine));
```

I've used the same code to read files with no escape characters and it works perfectly...
P.S. Not only `\n` wouldn't work, but also `\"` and probably any other.

Comment: you have try html <br/> tag instead of \n?

Comment: Can you change the format of input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
String source = "<br>"+String.valueOf(theLine);  
textGenerateNumber.append(Html.fromHtml(source));
```

Comment: I'll try it in an hour or so, sry for the delay

Comment: Should i change all the \n in the file to <br>'s Because with only those two lines it wouldn't work. :(

Comment: Since you can modify the file: Why you don't use "real" newlines? That way your file also is more readable.

Comment: Yes sir you are correct, THANK YOU very much. It took me so long to find a working solution. It works! And to answer the second question, it would be too hard for me to make the app find a random joke and display it.

Comment: Now i just need to figure out how to use it with .setText, since in that way it puts every new joke bellow the last one. But it should put it, over the joke :(

Comment: Yep figured it all out, i just need to add a little change to your code. Since it would start with new line every time i made it like this: 
String source = String.valueOf(theLine)+"<br>";  
textGenerateNumber.setText("");
textGenerateNumber.append(Html.fromHtml(source));

That does the job perfectly! Doesn't start with a new line, gives me new lines when i want and displays only the newest joke, thank you one more time.

Comment: By the way, just to add, this works for MOST of the devices but NOT for all of them, i had reports for LG GT 540, that wouldn't display new lines.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have

```
\n
```

in the file, and that are 2 normal characters, not a newline.

You can use Apache Commons library to unescape these sequences:

[StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) in Apache Commons.

Comment: I came across this link few days ago but couldn't realize how to make it work for me. Thx for the answer.